# The convergence of the adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

If a sequence of operator $A_n$ converges in norm to $A$, i.e. $\lim \lVert A_n-A\rVert=0$)where $A_n$ and $A\in B(H)$ ($H$ is the Hilbert space). Is it true that $A_n^*$ converges in norm to $A^*$?

Comment: So you mean norm convergence?

Comment: Yes I mean norm convergence

Comment: Actually, an operator has the same norm as the norm of its adjoint.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Get it.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(A_n-A)^*=A_n^*-A^*$ and an operator has the same norm with the adjoint operator,so $||A_n-A||=||A_n^*-A^*||$,then we get the answer.

Comment: The step "an operator has the same norm as its adjoint" deserves more details.